# T-mobile stock: difference between TMUSP vs TMUS

Tags: stocks, investing, dividends, yahoo-finance

Is there a way to invest in T-mobile stock from the US?  Yahoo finance lists both:

- TMUSP - NasdaqGS with a dividend of 4.3% and avg volume of 90,000 and
- TMUS - NasdaqGS with a dividend of 7.4% and avg volume of 4.4 million

I assume both of these are treated as normal 'C-corp' stocks (neither looks like a partnership or LLC subsidiary), so what is the difference?

Comment: As i noted in a comment on an answer below, the dividend data on these appears to be wrong on Yahoo! Finance. I cross-checked on two other sources.  TMUS is currently paying no dividend.  TMUSP is currently paying 4.38%.

Comment: @Brick What sources did you use?  Dividend.com has no data for either of them.

Comment: I checked Google Finance, my own broker, and nasdaq.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between TMUSP and TMUS is that the "with P" ticker is for a TMobile Preferred Stock offering.  The "without P" ticker is for TMobile common stock.  The difference between the apparent percentage yields is due to Yahoo! Stock misreporting the dividend on the preferred stock for the common stock, which has not paid a dividend (thanks Brick for pointing this out!)

Preferred stock holders get paid first in the event of liquidation, in most scenarios they get paid first.  They sometimes get better returns.  They typically lack voting rights, and after a grace period, they may be recalled by the company at a fixed price (set when they were issued).

Common stock holders can vote to alter the board of directors, and are the epitome of the typical "I own a trivial fraction of the company" model that most people think of when owning stocks.

As the common stock is valued at much less, it appears that the percent yield is much higher, but in reality, it's 0%.

Comment: I deleted my earlier comment after your fixes.

Comment: @Brick Thank you very much for your commentary.  It really made the difference between a poor answer and a good one.